# AlarmManager not repeating correctly

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I try to have a notification repeated daily (For debugging I set it to every 10s). However, it is firing the notification only the first time, then nothing happens.

Here is the code where the alarm is set:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(ctx , NotifyService.class);
AlarmManager alarmManager =(AlarmManager)ctx.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ctx, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 10, pendingIntent);
```

and here is the service:

```
public class NotifyService extends Service {
   public NotifyService() {

   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(){
       //Create and Emit the notification.
   }
```

I have tried different flags in `getService(ctx, int, Intent, flags)`, to use `setInexactRepeating` and to set a new alarm after every call to the `NotifyService`.

Comment: Try change setRepeating() to setInexactRepeating() for api >= 19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the method below to repeating the alarm once in a day and you have to register broadcast receiver instead of service with [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) so that you can start your service from the receiver and that is recommended.

Find the [official doc](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html).

```
     private final static String ACTION = "ACTION_ALARM";
     public static void setWakeUpAction(Context context, String hourSet, String minuteSet, String periodSet, int requestCode, String currentAction) {
            try {
                String mHour = hourSet;
                String mMin = minuteSet;
                String[] parsedFormat = null;
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
                Date date = parseFormat.parse(mHour + ":" + mMin + " " + periodSet);
                parsedFormat = displayFormat.format(date).split(":");
                mHour = parsedFormat[0];
                mMin = parsedFormat[1];
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(mHour));
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(mMin));
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);
                myIntent.putExtra(ACTION, currentAction);
                myIntent.putExtra("Time", new String[]{mHour, mMin, periodSet});
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

**BroadCastReceiver**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private final String ACTION = "ACTION_ALARM";
    private String ACTION_ONE = "ALARM_REPEAT";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       try {
            String action = intent.getStringExtra(ACTION);
            new ShowToast(context, action);
            if (action.length() > 1) {
                if (action.equals(ACTION_ONE) ) {
                  String time[] = intent.getStringArrayExtra("Time");
                  startService(context, action);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

    public void startService(Context context, String action) {
        Intent service1 = new Intent(context, NotifyService.class);
        service1.putExtra(ACTION, action);
        context.startService(service1);
    }

}
```

**Manifest**

```
   <service
        android:name=".NotifyService"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" />
```

**Usage**

```
setWakeUpAction(context, "11", "00","AM","0", "ALARM_REPEAT");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `PendingIntent` for a `BroadcastReceiver` rather than a `Service`, that is the recommended (and documented) practice. Plus, if you are using "wakeup" alarms, you'll need to use a `BroadcastReceiver` otherwise the system will not guarantee that it stays awake long enough for your `Service` to actually execute and receive the `Intent`.  See this article for more details: http://po.st/7UpipA

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

// setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
// 10 seconds.
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        1000 * 10, alarmIntent);
```

Refer : http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html